# Переклад слова "перелинковка"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно перекласти слово ***["перелинковка"](https://seopult.ru/library/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)***

> (от англ. *link* — ссылка) —процесс связывания гиперссылками разных
>   сайтов и страниц одного сайта между собой.

[Google](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/uk/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) перекладач подає як *перелінковка, перелинковка, перепосилання*.

Який варіант стилістично та нормативно правильно вживати?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Перел**и**нковка* очевидно відпадає, бо немає підстав уживати там *-и-* (ані за [правилом дев'ятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), ані за [якимись іншими приписами](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90)).

*Перепосилання* очевидно теж, бо це слово не відбиває змісту процесу. *Пере-* зазвичай означає повторення дії, понаднормову дію або дію (зазвичай рух) через щось, і тому *перепосилання* особисто мені інтерпретується як «повторне посилання». Це не лише не відбиває зміст процесу (зв'язування сайту чи декількох сайтів множиною посилань), а й спонукає сприймати оте *посилання* як процес (хоча в оригіналі малося на увазі радше link/посилання як елемент сайту).

Відповідно залишається *перел**і**нковка*.

Очевидно, що це жаргон/сленг, а не нейтральне слово (і російське *перелинковка*, звісно, теж). І в загальному випадку я не впевнений, що такий термін узагалі потрібен, адже:

- наскільки я бачу, в англійській мові немає окремого слова для цієї дії;
- наскільки я бачу, це слово позначає дві різні речі: зв'язування сторінок власного сайту посиланнями (internal links) і зв'язування власного сайту посиланнями з чужими сайтами, тобто фактично розміщення посилань, що вказують на власний сайт, на чужих сайтах (external links) — принаймні [наведене запитувачем джерело](//seopult.ru/library/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) підганяє обидві ці речі під російське слово *перелинковка*.

Але якщо обирати між цими трьома, то я однозначно би надав перевагу *перел**і**нковці*.

Comment: Можливо англійською це буде cross-referencing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-reference

Comment: @Artemix, дякую, так. Але _cross-referencing_ все-таки ширше поняття. Cross-referencing може стосуватися багато чого, а не лише гіперпосилань на сайтах, що створюються (гіперпосилання) задля SEO; і поки що я не бачив застосування цього слова саме в контексті SEO (хоча, може, погано шукав).

Comment: Тут вживають термін Link Building: https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/growing-popularity-and-links "As with any marketing activity, the first step in any link building campaign is the creation of goals and strategies. Unfortunately, link building is one of the most difficult activities to measure. Although the engines internally weigh each link with precise, mathematical metrics, it's impossible for those on the outside to access this information".

Comment: @Artemix, це вже два слова. (І я уважно не читав, але склалося враження, що там більше про зовнішні посилання з надійних майданчиків — а не про внутрішні.) (Тобто те саме: (а) навіть англійською це не одним словом; (б) немає сенсу ліпити в один термін дві настільки різні з практичної точки зору речі — ІМХО.) І я не впевнений, що це («link building») — саме термін, а не просто словосполучення.